# How to create a JS function on a dynamically generated Rails table

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a JS function to increment the count of the vote on the page, which I would usually do by writing `Document.getElementByID` and then writing in the ID, but in Rails, I am trying to figure out how to write this function where the table rows are being created dynamically in a loop. How would I create a function to do this?

Here's the html rails loop:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @requests.each do |request| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= request.artist %></td>
        <td><%= request.title %></td>
        <td><%= request.voteCount %></td>
        <td><button onclick="upVote()">Vote</button></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options:  If you want to stick with your onclick handler, just pass the request ID to your upVote() function.  That might look like this:

```
<td><button onclick="upVote(<%= request.id %>)">Vote</button></td>
```

Then, in your JS `upVote(requestID)` function, do whatever needs to be done to make that request and update your UI accordingly.

Another, superior, option would be to use Rails' built-in [remote link_to helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to), which is powered by rails-ujs.  Here's how that might look:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Vote', [:upvote, request], remote: true, method: :post, class: 'upvote' %></td>
```

Note that I'm using the POST method, since actions that have side-effects should not be done with a GET request.  Make sure you route accordingly.

Then in your RequestsController:

```
def upvote
  request = Request.find(params[:id])
  request.upvote! # Or do whatever you need to do to upvote it

  # Respond to your JS request with whatever updated info it might need to update the UI
  render json: { voteCount: request.voteCount } } 
end
```

Finally, in JS (written as CoffeeScript):

```
$('a.upvote').on 'ajax:success', (event) ->
  # Update your UI to reflect the upvote (you can access the JSON returned from your upvote action here to make necessary updates)
```

Comment: In the first method you mentioned, how would I get the element in order to update? Heres my JS code `function upVote(requestID) {
        var count = document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML;
        count = parseInt(count);
        count = count + 1;
        count = count.toString();
        document.getElementById("voteCount").innerHTML = count;
        document.getElementById("voteButton").disabled = "true";
  }`

Comment: One option would be to add a data-request-id attribute to maybe the <tr>, so something like: `<tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">`.  Then in your JS, you could find it again with `$("tr[data-request-id='" + requestID +"']")`.  But I'd strongly recommend checking out the rails-ujs approach.

Comment: Id like to try the Rails way but Im new to rails and I think im going to have a tougher time implementing it. Im trying it and getting an error `undefined method `upvote_request_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f08348ab270>:0x00007f08348a8d68>`

Comment: the html is `  <tbody>
    <% @requests.each do |request| %>
      <tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">
        <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.artist %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.title %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center" class="voteCount"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><button class = "voteButton" onclick="upVote()">Vote</button></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Vote', [:upvote, request], remote: true, method: :post, class: 'upvote' %></td>
      </tr>`

Comment: You need to add a route for your upvote action.  Check out the Routing guide.  In general, the Rails guide are your friends.  They are incredibly well written and informative - I'd encourage anyone new to Rails to at least skim them to get a sense for how the various components all fit together. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: OK im working on this and I understand the routing now, I'm making some changes to the routes.rb file to accomodate the necessary routing. I don't think the "undefined method" error is due to routing issues though. Any other ideas?

Comment: I advised you to pass `[:upvote, request]` to `link_to`.  That's shorthand for `upvote_request_path(request)` which uses the dynamically built `upvote_request_path` helper, and assumes that you've got a resourceful route like: `resources :requests do; post :upvote; end`.  Feel free to replace `[:upvote, request]` with the route helper for your actual `upvote` action.